# Is this proof about continuity and boundedness correct?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, compactness

I wanted to know if my proof is okay or not. I feel like near the end, it is incorrect, which I will explain. The question is:

Let $f:\mathbb{R^{m}}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^{n}}$ be continuous on $\mathbb{R^{m}}$ and $D\subseteq\mathbb{R^{m}}$ be bounded. Show that $f\left(D\right)\subseteq\mathbb{R^{n}}$ is bounded.

My Answer:

Since $D$ is bounded, then by the Bolzano–Weierstrass Theorem, for every sequence $\left(x_n\right)\in D$, there exists a convergent subsequence $\left(x_{n_k}\right)$. Let $\lim\left(x_{n_k}\right)=x$. Since $f$ is continuous, then $\lim\left(f\left(x_{n_k}\right)\right)=f\left(x\right)$. Since every subsequence $\left(f\left(x_{n_k}\right)\right)\in f\left(D\right)$ converges, then $f\left(D\right)$ is sequentially compact. Thus, $f\left(D\right)$ is compact (since compactness and sequential compactness are equivalent in a metric space), so it is bounded.

At the end, I am not sure if the claim that $f\left(D\right)$ is compact is true. If a subset of a metric space is compact, then it is closed and bounded. But I don't intuitively see how $f\left(D\right)$ is closed when we only know that $D$ is bounded.

Comment: You are correct. Consider $m=n=1$, then let $D$ be $(0,1)$ and $f$ be the identity map. Clearly, $f$ is continuous and $D$ is bounded, but $f(D)$ is not compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using compactness to show boundedness is brilliant, but there is a small error in your argument. Since $D$ is not necessarily closed, the limit $\lim x_{n_k}=x$ might lie outside of $D$. To remedy it, you may consider the closure of $D$, denoted $\overline{D}$, instead of $D$ in your whole argument. Then your argument carries nicely, and in the end, you are able to show that $f(\overline{D})$ is compact thus bounded. Since $f(D)$ is a subset of $f(\overline{D})$, it's also bounded.

Comment: Also, as $D$ is bounded, $\overline{D}$ will be closed and bounded, thus compact. If you know that continuous functions map compact sets to compact sets, the argument shortens considerably, without having to pass to sequences.

Comment: Thanks! You and @kholli made me realize that I forgot one of the very important parts of compactness: that the limit must lie inside of the set.